# LINQ query to retrieve from one table and then another

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables containing the same fields,
e.g. `id`,`name`,`invoiceNo`..etc

I want to use c# ling to get all the data from both tables

I have the below example for 1 table, how do I add the second table?

```
 return query = from tb1 in dataContext.tbl1
                    select new customer
                    {
                       name= tbl1.name
                    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `Concat` once you have two sequences of the same type.

```
return dataContext.tbl1.Select(tb1 => new customer()
{
    name = tb1.name,
})
.Concat(dataContext.tbl2
    .Select(tb2 => new customer()
    {
         name = tb2.name,
    }));
```

You could use query syntax for the `select` calls, but I find method syntax preferable in this particular case.

Comment: Hi Servy, I tried your code, you are using "new" anonymous type, how do I assign the values to a class I already have, "customer" class? so data from both tables are stored in one class? because later the function need return IEnumerable<customer> object thanks

Comment: @Ben You do it the same way you did it in your OP.  I just forgot to add it as I was writing them out.

Comment: I get this error, Cannot initialize type 'Customers' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable', is it something to do with my class object?

Comment: @Ben Sorry, added the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Union` or `Concat`:

```
query1 = from tb1 in dataContext.tbl1
                select new customer
                {
                   name= tbl1.name
                };

query2 = from tb2 in dataContext.tbl2
                    select new customer
                    {
                       name= tbl1.name
                    };

var resQuery = query1.Union(query2);
```

It would be similar with `Concat`. Main difference between `Union` and `Concat` is that `Union` removes duplicities from the result.

Comment: Why are you adding the `ToList`?  It's not in the OP's code.  It appears to be a method that will be called various contexts in which the query will be further added to, it would be a major problem to bring it all into memory here.

Comment: It is just an example - I can immediately try that this portion of query works as expected and later I can remove it. But I agree that there is no need for that `ToList()`

Comment: It's not just that it's not needed, it's actively harmful and is likely to cause significant problems unless noticed and removed.  If you're testing the method for the first time and want to evaluate the results in a list then you would add a `ToList` on the *caller* side, when testing it, not within the method where it needs to be removed.

Comment: OK, I agree and removed it. For Linq very very beginners it could be harmful to see such code if they won't be aware of what `ToList` is actually doing.

Comment: Even if that's not the case, it's still something they'll need to go out of their way to remove, so adding it is at best an annoyance.

Comment: thank you all for your help, could you please explain me why ToList() is harmful to use? I always use ToList() to get the list and then load it into a ddl or gridview? I am new to all of this and appreciate your help

Comment: @Ben If you intend to call any additional `IQueryable` methods, such as a `Where`, any ordering, or any other actions that ought to be performed on the database then it wouldn't be happening on the database, you'd be pulling the objects into memory and using linq to objects.

Comment: It is harmful if you use it unwisely. For example if you query your db like `dataContext.tbl1.ToList()` it will retrieve all records from `tbl1` in memory and in case there are lot of records it is problem. So it is better to put some where conditions according to your bussines needs so the results set will be reduced according the condition and hit `ToList()` on the last point where you actually need to retrieve the data.